# Output all elements from php array and count their occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count, element

This is part of my multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
            [1] => ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 102
            [1] => ...
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 102
            [1] => ...
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 102
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
        )
)
```

My goal is to get all elements with id [0] without repeating the same elements but with number of their occurrences in brackets, like this output:

```
101
102(3)
30
test(2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0 needed for `array_column()`:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_column($array, 0));
```

For < 5.5.0 replace `array_column()` with:

```
array_map(function($v) { return $v[0]; }, $array)
```

Then:

```
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k ($v)";
}
```

Comment: thanks, what should I do, if my array elements I want to count are not the same, but e.g. 102a, 102b, 102c and I want them to be counted as 3 occurrences, some kind of preg_match maybe?

Comment: Different ways depending on the data.  For your example `return (int)$v[0];` would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use `print_r(array_count_values($array));` and it will return you the count what u needed.

```
$array = array(101, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 7);
print_r(array_count_values($array));

Result:

Array
( [1] => 1 ,[2] => 1 , [3] => 3, [4] => 2,[5] =>1, [6] => 4, [7] => 1 )
```

Comment: Uhhh... Except that's not representative of the OP's array.